# Error with Python import

Tags: python, django, django-models, import, python-import

I have problem:

I am using this package: https://github.com/ulule/django-badgify

It works perfectly, but now I need to create Custom model Badge. I have made everything, as  in docs:

main.models.py:

```
from badgify.models.base.badge import Badge as BaseBadge

class GuidaBadge(BaseBadge):
    class Meta(BaseBadge.Meta):
        abstract = False
```

settings.py:

```
BADGIFY_BADGE_MODEL = "main.models.GuidaBadge"
```

But it cause error:

```
  File "D:\virtenvs\codeguida\codeguida\main\models.py", line 11, in <module>
    from badgify.models.base.badge import Badge as BaseBadge
  File "D:\virtenvs\codeguida\lib\site-packages\badgify\models\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    Badge = load_class(settings.BADGE_MODEL)
  File "D:\virtenvs\codeguida\lib\site-packages\badgify\utils.py", line 88, in load_class
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured(txt)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Backend module "main.models" does not define a "GuidaBadge" class.
```

That is, https://github.com/ulule/django-badgify/blob/master/badgify/utils.py#L79

It seems that Python can`t find "GuidaBadge" class. So I have tried to use function load_class() in shell - it return right class...

I think that the error cause, in this way:

As we can see in Traceback, firstly:

```
File "D:\virtenvs\codeguida\codeguida\main\models.py", line 11, in <module>
        from badgify.models.base.badge import Badge as BaseBadge
```

Program asks python to import `Badge` class from badgify package

Then Python tried to import it, and encounter with

```
File "D:\virtenvs\codeguida\lib\site-packages\badgify\models\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        Badge = load_class(settings.BADGE_MODEL)
```

Here program asks python to load_class from string (that is stored in settings, e.g. 'main.models.GuidaBadge')

But Python has not run this part of models, yet. And it cause error that there is not class "GuidaBadge" in "main.models".

Am I right?

How to fix it?

Comment: It could be a circular import. Take a look at what you are importing on settings to see if you have any circular dependencies

Comment: Can explain some more? Please?

Answer (score 1):

dont do

```
from badgify.models.base.badge import Badge as BaseBadge
```

instead do

```
import badgify.models.base.badge

class GuidaBadge(badgify.models.base.badge.Badge):
    class Meta(BaseBadge.Meta):
        abstract = False
```

"from" and "as" imports are having problems with circularity because of namespace changes (the from imported module is not recognized as the original model because it is imported as a different namespace).

Answer (score 1):

> main.models.py:

Is your file named that way or is it `models.py` that lives in `main` directory? If first one, change it to second one.

Check also that you have `__init__.py` file in main directory and that your main directory lives in python path.

Comment: But what is the "python path"?